# how to find weekdays from specific week in Flutter?

Tags: datetime, flutter, week-number

For example 20.week contain May 11, 2020 - May 17, 2020

The code have to show these date range. But the code shows : 2020-05-12 - 2020-05-18

Here's the code

```
DateTime getDateByWeekNumber({
  int week,
  int year,
  bool start
}) {
  DateTime date;
  var days = ((week - 1) * 7) + (start ? 0: 6);
  date = DateTime.utc(2020, 1, days);
  return date;
}
```

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[The ISO 8601 definition for week 01 is the week with the Gregorian year's first Thursday in it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date)

We need found out if `first day of a year` is before `Thursday`

```
DateTime getDateByWeekNumber({int week, int year, bool start}) {
  DateTime startOfaYear = DateTime.utc(year, 1, 1);
  int startOfaYearWeekDay = startOfaYear.weekday;
  DateTime firstWeekOfaYear = startOfaYearWeekDay < 4
      ? startOfaYear.subtract(Duration(days: startOfaYearWeekDay - 1))
      : startOfaYear.add(Duration(days: 8 - startOfaYearWeekDay));
  DateTime startOfNWeek = firstWeekOfaYear.add(Duration(days: (week - 1) * 7));
  return start ? startOfNWeek : startOfNWeek.add(Duration(days: 6));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answering.. Your code  works smoothly for year of  2020 but does not work for 2021

Comment: Edited `startOfaYear.add(Duration(days: 8 - startOfaYearWeekDay));`

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
DateTime getDateByWeekNumber({int week, int year, bool start}) {
 DateTime date;
 var days = ((week - 1) * 7) + (start ? -1 : 5);
 date = DateTime.utc(2020, 1, days);
 return date;
}
```

Comment: Output of your code is
Start Date for week 1: 2020-01-01 
End Date for week 1: 2020-01-01


But it should start at :
Start Date for week 2: 2019-12-30
End Date for week 1: 2020-01-05 , thanks for attention.

Comment: i Updated the code, I used -1 as start because as this year has started from Wednesday and to match the output it should add 5 to match the start day